# How can I find specific block name in structure->blocks in drupal-7?

Tags: 7, blocks

I can see specific block in the home page. I need to show this block in specific roles. How I can find this block in the list of blocks in structure->blocks?

Comment: You could enable the contextual links module and hover over the block and click the small gear icon to edit the block.  Or you could figure out what region the block is in using firebug or similar which will narrow it down in the block administration page assuming the block is set that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did that and have specified roles to this block. but still couldn't find it when I login by a user of this role.

Comment: You could try flushing your cache after making sure you have the user's role and block settings correct

Comment: Still I can see the block for administrator and I cannot find it in the other role. Is there any thing else I can check?

Comment: If you uncheck all roles so that anyone can view it, can you see the block when not logged in?  Depending on what the block is or is displaying you might have to check the permissions for whatever module creates the block at `/admin/people/permissions`

Comment: I unchecked all roles and still cannot see this block except by admin. By the way, this block is related to relationship actions of user relationship module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15099/discussion-between-user3377708-and-patrick-ryan).

Comment: Then the block does not have any content to display to the user, you will have to make sure that whatever content the block is supposed to show is available for the user to view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support :) I found it when I tried to grant privileges to this role one by one. but I'm still wonder if there is a way better than what I did!?

Comment: No problem, I'll move my suggestions to an answer since it helped you find your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could enable the contextual links module and hover over the block and click the small gear icon to edit the block.
2. you could figure out what region the block is in using firebug or similar which will narrow it down in the block administration page assuming the block is set that way.

If the block is still not visible, the specific user/role may not have the permissions to see whatever content you are trying to view.  Check the permissions for the role at `/admin/people/permissions`